# Restore to operation in seconds on failure?

Tags: restore, architecture

My customer have a requirement on SharePoint Server to restore itself on failure within seconds. I’m told that it should work as Hotel electricity backup in a Nigerian Hotel:

> If the power fails, the diesel engine powers up and the light goes on again in two or three seconds.

The customer is very small (less than a hundred) who handles 1’000’000 documents. Not all documents need that high availability, but chances are that up to 10% of the volume need this restore to operation feature in second.

However, being a nice feature, is it possibly to implement? If so – how would that be done without adding a million dollar quote to the customer?

Comment: Is it the front/app servers we are concerned about, or is it the SQL? Could you not just create a farm where all roles are distributed to at least 2 servers (and where SQL is mirrored on two servers)?

Comment: @RobertLindgren Both really. Would the mirroring self-restore within the given timeframe?

Comment: Not sure about "within seconds", but if you configure mirroring correctly the SharePoint databases will know of the mirroring server and alter from the primary server to the mirror automatically: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207314(v=office.14).aspx. But, mirroring do require very low network latency so I guess separating the failover servers geographically (for powerloss etc. ) could be a greater challange than the actual config

Comment: @RobertLindgren Power loss isn't an issue we need to address, since the customer say they already have all the UPS they  need. Fortiunately for us. I guess 2 WFE, 2 App server and database mirroring would do the trick here. Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess that setup would get you well on the way! :D

Comment: @RobertLindgren Most definately. Write the answer and I'll mark it as accepted, Robert. Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it the front/app servers we are concerned about, or is it the SQL?

You could create a farm where all roles (web app, application, crawl, index) are distributed to at least 2 servers (and where SQL is mirrored on two servers).

I'm not sure about "within seconds", but if you [configure mirroring correctly](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207314(v=office.14).aspx) the SharePoint databases will know of the mirroring server and alter from the primary server to the mirror automatically.

But, mirroring do require very low network latency (the article above mentions 1ms!) so I guess separating the failover servers geographically (for powerloss etc.) could be a greater challenge than the actual configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues here.

The first one is power outage. To prevent the servers (and all the network equipment which you need them to be able to answer requests ...) to die when the power fails, you need [uninterruptible power supplies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninterruptible_power_supply). They are pretty cheap and keep the servers alive for a couple of minutes until power returns. They also protect against power surges and tiny outages, so they are good in all places where electrical power is unreliable.

The second one is server failure (Windows crashes). To prevent against that, you need mirror servers and load balancing as described in [Robert's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/117412/34075).